# Which Data Structure should i use in this C++ project?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

i need some help in deciding which data structure i should use. i'm going to create a patient information system of a hospital just like a simple student information system.

i have studied Arrays, Linked Lists, Trees, Stacks, Queues and Graphs. i think it would be too simple with Array. should i use linked list?

how will i store all the fields into it? a Linked list stores one item of data at the moment, no?   my requirements are to add information, search them by their ID and be able to delete through ID as well.

any ideas? thanks

Comment: _"i want to use as many data structures in this as possible"_ You should sort out your requirements clearly first, before choosing data structures to realize these.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question... I feel like answering that you should use a `Patient` class of your own construction. Why doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: @DanielT. It's very certainly more than a simple single `Patient` class (e.g. stored in a `std::vector<Patient>`) needed to implement such a system.

Comment: _"my requirements are to add information, search them by their ID and be able to delete through ID as well."_ Something like a `std::map<int,Patient>` where the key is the `Patient.ID` sounds appropriate for me.

Comment: I don't think this question deserved the downvotes, but I can understand the request for further requirements. Design all of the workflows that you actually need or might need to accomplish. I imagine it will be more than just pulling up a single patient's information, or removing a single patient. It will probably need to be flexible, and you might desire a true database.

Comment: `i think it would be too simple with Array. should i use linked list?` So you aren't looking for a simple solution? I thought it's what all programers are looking for.

Comment: @Drop it's a project and not using arrays is kinda requirement.

Comment: @Alamgir then your phrase is misleading and you should add this new information to the question. Are only arrays disallowed or, let's say, `std::vector` too? Other standard containers like `std::map`?

Comment: Notice that "I have studied Arrays, Linked Lists, Trees, Stacks, Queues and Graphs" is ambiguous. You either have learned how to implement these, or you have learned the STL containers and how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

> my requirements are to add information, search them by their ID and be able to delete through ID as well.

Seems like an `std::map<id, patient>` would suit your needs via:

- `operator[]` to add a record
- `at`/`find` for retrieval
- `erase` for removal

If you need more complex queries I'd recommend a full-fledged relational database.

Comment: Did you consider `id` to be a `typedef int id;`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `id` can be whatever the user needs it to be. It's fairly irrelevant for the question. Even if `id` is a sequential integer, removals make `std::vector`, or array-like containers in general,  space inefficient in this case.